# Node.js embed isn't generating invite links

Tags: java, node.js, discord.js

not really sure what's going on with this code..
At one point, the code was working fine. Woke up the next day and it completely stopped working. Im not sure if something was updated, but its just weird.
JavaScript isn't my strongest language

Does anyone have any ideas? Me and 3 others have been stumped for a few days on this.
Thanks for any help!

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const { QuickDB } = require('quick.db');
const db = new QuickDB();
const config = require('../Database/config.json');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('farm')
    .setDescription('Join servers for coins!'),
async execute(interaction, client) {

    await interaction.deferReply();

    let orders = await db.all(`orders_`, { sort: ".data" })

    let length = 0;

    orders = orders.filter(x => x.data > 0 && client.guilds.cache.get(x.ID.split("_")[1]) 
&& client.guilds.cache.get(x.ID.split("_")[1]).members.cache.get(interaction.user.id) === 
undefined)

    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .setTitle('Farm!')

    for (let i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {

        let handler = true
        
        console.log(orders)
        

        if (length >= 1) { return; } else {

            let id = orders[i].ID.split("_")[1]

            let guild = client.guilds.cache.get(orders[i].ID.split("_")[1]).name

            let code = await db.get(`code_${id}`)


            await client.fetchInvite("https://discord.gg/" + code)
                .then(link => {
                    console.log(link.code)
                    if (link.code === null) handler = false
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    handler = false
                })

            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1))

            if (handler) {
                let description = await db.get(`description_${id}`)

                embed.setDescription(`${guild} - ${description}`,)
                length++
            }
         }
      }

        interaction.editReply({ embeds: [embed] });
    },
};
```

Comment: "stopped working". Please tell us with an [edit] what this means, with examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a link on embed:

```
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
.setDescription('[Testing Link](https://www.google.com/)') //Your HyperLink
message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
```

These should be your code looks like:

```
embed.setDescription(`[${guild}] - (${description})`)
```

[image: Something like these]

```
const guild = "Something Testing for a link";
const description = "https://www.google.com/";

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
.setDescription(`[${guild}](${description})`)
message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
```

Remember to start your Hyperlink with `https://` or `http://`

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly a typo in line 5:

```
onst config = require('../Database/config.json');
```

should be

```
const config = require('../Database/config.json');
```